# c# cefsharp browser trying to set proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, cefsharp

I'm not very good with CefSharp browsers so I need some outside help on this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;

 namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
    public partial class debug : Form
    {
        public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;

        public debug()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitBrowser();
        }


        private void debug_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void InitBrowser()
        {
            Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://whatismyipaddress.com/");     
            this.Controls.Add(browser);
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            CefSettings cfsettings = new CefSettings();
            cfsettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", "200.29.191.149:3128");
            cfsettings.UserAgent = "My/Custom/User-Agent-AndStuff";
            Cef.Initialize(cfsettings);


        }

    }
}
```

This is my current code.  I want it to use a proxy and I have been Googling for the past 3 hours now.  It's getting late, so I hope someone can help me insert the proxy in there.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a proxy type different "http", you must set it in proxy-schema e.g. as shown following

```
cfsettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", "socks5://200.29.191.149:3128");
```

You can read more in [CEF3 Documentation](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage#markdown-header-proxy-resolution)

Comment: dident work for me, still showing my local ip.

Comment: @nedn see my answer below. Sorry my English is bad

Answer (score 4):

You double set CefSettings. You must first configure. Configure is once in project and it should be before first call InitializeComponent() in your application.

```
public debug()
{
   Configure();
   InitializeComponent();
   CreateNewBrowser();
}

public void Configure()
{
   CefSettings cfsettings = new CefSettings();
   cfsettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", "200.29.191.149:3128");
   cfsettings.UserAgent = "My/Custom/User-Agent-AndStuff";
   Cef.Initialize(cfsettings);
}

public void CreateNewBrowser()
{
   browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://whatismyipaddress.com/");     
   this.Controls.Add(browser);
   browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;     
}
```

Comment: it works without the ip but when i try to put a proxy it doesnt do anything.

Comment: @nedn you created new project? You test it on different proxy? what showing event OnWebBrowserLoadError?

Comment: its the same project and yes i tested multiple proxy's even private proxies.
and i dont understand the last part. but when i comment the cfsettings proxy thingy it loads fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have same trouble with `SefSharp3`. 
I launch `CEF3` with same configurations

`--proxy-server=...`

and it works fine. I think it is a bug. And `CefSharp3` have so much bugs I will use `C++` `CEF` sources.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19366851)

Comment: ok, sorry, but I think it may be helpfull for someone